# Error while running autodocktools

Tags: docking

I have just installed Adt package in ubuntu 14.10 using command

```
sudo apt-get install autodocktools
```

and following error is occurring while launching Adt (>runAdt)

```
TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside .140134053349568.140134053350072.140133987942984.140133987945216 which already has slaves managed by pack
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: This sounds similar to the problem others have had running ADT.  In most cases the problem was in their python imaging libraries.  Try googling the problem.  There are many posts about your problem.

Comment: @RCF I've googled the problem but couldn't find any answer

Comment: Try googling mgltools, that may have been the way I found it. I searched for "Ubuntu errors running autodocktools.  I found many forums and suggested scripts for installing and debugging errors.

Comment: @RCF I have tried everything but couldn't find any solution.